# Cython additional typing and cimport for numpy array slow down the performance?

Tags: indexing, numpy, cython

Below are two simple Cython methods I wrote. In g_cython() method I used additional typing for numpy array a and b, but surprisingly g_cython() is twice slower than g_less_cython(). I wonder why is this happening? I thought adding that would make indexing on a and b much faster?

PS. I understand both functions can be vectorized in numpy -- I am just exploring cython optimization tricks.

```
import numpy as np; 
cimport numpy as np;

def g_cython(np.ndarray[np.int_t, ndim = 1] a, percentile):
    cdef int i
    cdef int n = len(a)
    cdef np.ndarray[np.int_t, ndim = 1] b = np.zeros(n, dtype = 'int')
    for i in xrange(n):
        b[i] = np.searchsorted(percentile, a[i])
    return b


def g_less_cython(a, percentile):
    cdef int i
    b = np.zeros_like(a)
    for i in xrange(len(a)):
        b[i] = np.searchsorted(percentile, a[i])
    return b
```

my test case is when len(a) == 1000000 and len(percentile) = 100

```
def main3():
    n = 100000
    a = np.random.random_integers(0,10000000,n)
    per = np.linspace(0, 10000000, 101)

    q = time.time()
    b = g_cython(a, per)
    q = time.time() - q
    print q

q = time.time()
bb = g_less_cython(a, per)
q = time.time() - q
print q
```

Comment: For me, your code doesn't build as written - you need an import and cimport of numpy, and on line 4, you need to pass something like `dtype=int` to `np.zeros`, otherwise it creates an array of doubles (though maybe this is dependent on the version of cython?).  Also, it would help if you provided a typical usage example.  Anyway, if you want to compare what cython is doing in each case, you can build the file with `cython -a`, which gives you a nicely formatted html file, in which clicking on lines of python code reveals the corresponding generated C code.

Comment: @James Thanks for your reply. I skipped the cimport and import part as I thought it would be distracting to post those lines in the code. I added the dtype part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested you code, g_cython is a slightly faster than g_less_cython.

here is the test code

```
import pyximport; pyximport.install()
import search_sorted
import numpy as np
import time
x = np.arange(100000, dtype=np.int32)
y = np.random.randint(0, 100000, 100000)

start = time.clock()
search_sorted.g_cython(y, x)
print time.clock() - start

start = time.clock()
search_sorted.g_less_cython(y, x)
print time.clock() - start
```

the output is:

```
0.215430514708
0.259622599945
```

I turned off the boundscheck and wraparound flag:

```
@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
def g_cython(np.ndarray[np.int_t, ndim = 1] a, percentile):
    ....
```

The difference is not notable because the call of np.searchsorted(percentile, a[i]) is the critical part that used most of CPU.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Even for your test case, I still don't get your results. g_less_cython() is still faster. and I posted my test case.

Comment: by the way what platform are you using? I didn't think time.clock() provides much accuracy?

Comment: I use windows XP, time.clock() is accuracy enough, http://docs.python.org/library/time.html?time.clock#time.clock